# ACRA dialog and email destination on crash android

Tags: android, acra

I am trying to add the crash dump sent to me my email support using acra.
I believe there is an option to show a dialog on restart of app.

Below is my reportCrash

```
    @ReportsCrashes(formKey="dGVacG0ydVHnaNHjRjVTUTEtb3FPWGc6MQ",
mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
customReportContent = { ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
        ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA,
        ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT },                

resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text, // optional, displayed as soon as the crash occurs, before collecting data which can take a few seconds
resDialogText = R.string.crash_dialog_text,
resDialogIcon = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info, //optional. default is a warning sign
resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_dialog_title, // optional. default is your application name
resDialogCommentPrompt = R.string.crash_dialog_comment_prompt, // optional. when defined, adds a user text field input with this text resource as a label
resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_dialog_ok_toast // optional. displays a Toast message when the user accepts to send a report.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to show the dialog on restart of your app, it normally shows when the crash occurs before the app is killed. But the config that you have there looks correct for dialog display.

One word of warning, the use of Google docs to capture the crash reports is now deprecated. You should look for another crash reporting back end like Acralyzer.

Comment: IF i add a mailto option, I dont see any action on preparing or sending an email. I just get thank you